# Effective computation of matrix commutator

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a faster way to compute the commutator of large (at least one of them sparse) matrices $[A,B]$ then to compute $AB$ ,$BA$ and subtract them?

Comment: If it helps, I can assume that one of them is sparse and hermitian.

Comment: Any matrix-matrix multiplication routine can be adapted for computing commutators. It depends on what matrices do you consider (sparse/dense, sparse/sparse) and in what format.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: sparse/dense, one real symmetric and one real either symmetric or antisymmetric. Any hint please?

Comment: If the matrices are dense then of course the classical level-3 BLAS algorithms could be adapted. For sparse matrices, the simple algorithm by [Gustavson](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355796). Anyway, the "best" algorithm depends on how the matrices are stored (but usually the dot product formulations are the worst). Since the matrices have a sort of symmetry (as well as the commutators), only a "half" actually needs to be stored. However, I'm not sure that this would actually help anything except for issues with memory access and cache misses.